# problems of installing kde runtime libraries on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, kde-plasma, kdevelop

I am trying to install kde runtime libraries for kscope on Linux (2.6.18-308.11.1.el5).

http://kscope.sourceforge.net/install.shtml

I have downloaded kde-runtime-4.9.2 from ftp://ftp.kde.org/pub/kde/stable/4.9.2/src/

But, in the downloaded files, I cannot find INSTALL or other help files about how to install it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Q: What version of Linux?  Is doing an "apt-get" or "yum install" an option for your version?  For example, will `su -c 'yum update kde-runtime'` do what you need?

Comment: I do not have sys-adm authorization. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do(assuming you are not on kubuntu):

1) add kubuntu's backports to your existing ppa(to gain access to KDE libraries):
   # sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
2) Update the package index:
   # sudo apt-get update
3) Install kdebase-runtime deb package:
   # sudo apt-get install kdebase-runtime

this should work

cheers

Answer (score 0):

kscope had it's latest release in 2008 and depends on KDE 3 libraries.

kdelibs 4 are incompatible with kdelibs 3. To get it running you need a distribution that still supports kde3. (or compile kde3 all yourself)

I suggest you use an alternative application - like KDevelop (you actually tagged your question with kdevelop)